# Why swap(&a++,&b++) gives error "invalid lvalue in unary '&'"?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, swap, memory-address

```
#include<stdio.h>
int swap(int *a,int *b);
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    swap(&a++,&b++);
    printf("a=%d\nb=%d",a,b);
    return 0;
}

int swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
```

Why does this function give the error "invalid lvalue in unary '&'"?
Normal `swap(&a,&b)` works fine but `swap(&a++,&b++)` as well as `swap(&(a++),&(b++))` give errors. What's the reason behind this?

Comment: It is a language limitation. Likewise, you can't write `&(a+1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The post-increment operator returns a temporary version of the previous value contained in the variable on which the post-increment operation was performed.  This temporary value is not a l-value, or "named" memory location, therefore you can't take the address of that temporary using the unary address-of operator.

For instance, on certain architectures like x86, etc., a temporary value generated from the post-increment operator on a simple POD-type like a `int`, `long` etc. will be temporarily held in a CPU register, not an actual memory location.  In these instances you simply can't take the "address" of a CPU register.

Comment: +1 But your second paragraph isn't really relevant. Even a named lvalue doesn't need to be a memory location and can be a mere register value (especially in light of optimizations). But once you take its address it'll be put into memory (or maybe even not then, depending on the context).

Comment: I was simply trying to give a simple scenario for why this would be the case ... Optimizations obviously can flex the rules a bit, but as you point out in the end, a named memory location will have to somehow be associated with a given memory location and not a CPU register when using the address-of operator on it.